# get id of datepicker element in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
var disabledDays = [0, 6];
$(function()
{
        $(".showcal").datepicker({
        language: 'en',
        position:'top left',
        multipleDates:10,
        multipleDatesSeparator:', ',
        onRenderCell: function (date, cellType)
        {
            if (cellType == 'day')
            {
                var day = date.getDay(),
                isDisabled = disabledDays.indexOf(day) != -1;
                return 
                {
                    disabled: isDisabled
                }
            }
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

HTML is:

```
<div name="pubCalendar" class="showcal cp" id="pub1" value=""></div>
<div name="pubCalendar" class="showcal cp" id="pub2" value=""></div>    
<div name="pubCalendar" class="showcal cp" id="pub3" value=""></div>    
<div name="pubCalendar" class="showcal cp" id="pub4" value=""></div>
```

As above I have multiple datepickers and i want to set the **disabledDays  javascript variable** different for all of them.How can i do that?
In current code disabledDays is same for all of the datepickers but based on the datpicker which is getting initialised I also want to set the disabledDays  variable for it.
How can i achieve that.Pls help.

Comment: try changing  $(".showcal").datepicker({   to  $("#divid").datepicker({   and do whatever you want. The only change here will be you will have to initialize all 4 separately , but that is the only way out . I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple.

```
$('.showcal').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    //or
    console.log(this.id);
    // Here "this" means your current datepicker.
    // You can set your disabledDays here on $(this)
});
```

Comment: no this wont work because this will set disabled days to the last value I set based on id.

Comment: eg:if(this.id=="pub1")
              disabledDays = [0];
             if(this.id=="pub2")
              disabledDays = [0,6]; this will set disabledDays to [0,6] in datepicker for all calendars

Comment: Okay got it if we will put entire datepicker code in .each then this will work.Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
<script>
var disabledDays = [0, 6];
$(function()
{
$('.showcal').each(function()
{
    var id=this.id;
    if(this.id=="pub1")
                disabledDays = [0];
        if(this.id=="pub2")
                disabledDays = [0,6];
        $("#"+id).datepicker({
        language: 'en',
        position:'top left',
        multipleDates:10,
        multipleDatesSeparator:', ',
        onRenderCell: function (date, cellType)
        {
        if (cellType == 'day')
        {
            var day = date.getDay(),
            isDisabled = disabledDays.indexOf(day) != -1;
            return 
                {
                    disabled: isDisabled
                }
        }
        }
    })//End of datepicker function
  });//End of .each
});
</script>
```